# Specifying the default return while declaring an abstract method

Tags: java, abstract-class, return-value, abstract-methods

I have the following classes

The interface:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
  public abstract boolean checkSomething();
}
```

The class inheriting the abstract class:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass
{
  public boolean checkSomething()
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

When I create MyClass in eclipse the checkSomething() method is created automaticly but with false as the default return value. Is there a way to specify in an abstract method definition what the default return type shoud be?

Comment: Are you talking about the return value that eclipse automatically puts in your code, or a return value for the inherited function?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no such thing as a "default return value" in Java. Each implementation should decide that for itself - it's just the method templating that Eclipse uses which happens to have picked false. Given that you should be replacing the method body anyway, I don't see this as much of the problem.

If a default implementation of "just return true" is reasonable, it sounds like `checkSomething` shouldn't be abstract in the first place - that's where the default implementation would live, and be overridden by classes wanting to provide more specific behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [eclipse code templates](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-code-templates.htm)

Other than that, you can create your *custom annotations* to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a method body in an abstract method declaration. So there is no way to specify a default return value in an abstract method. This is independent from the IDE template.